# How to Serve Multiple Mongoose Actions in A single Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I Want to add this code to my App.get route

```
User.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundUser){
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    else {
       res.render("ranking", {currentUser: req.user ,location: req.originalUrl, user: foundUser});
    }
  });
```

This is my **App.get route**

```
app.get("/ranking",isLoggedIn , function(req, res){
  User.find({}).sort({points: -1}).exec(function(err, user) {
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    else {
  res.render("ranking",{currentUser: req.user, location: req.originalUrl, users: user});
    }
});
})
```

;

I need a good way to this code to the route above .... Thanks!
Should it be like this:

```
    app.get("/ranking",isLoggedIn , function(req, res){
  User.find({}).sort({points: -1}).exec(function(err, user) {
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    else {
      User.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundUser){
      if(err){console.log(err);}
      else {
        res.render("ranking",{currentUser: req.user, location: req.originalUrl, users: user});

      }
    });
    }
  });
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem? The code looks fine

Comment: Inside the else statement in the app.get route insert the findbyid call that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the else statement in the app.get route insert the findbyid call that you need.

You'd also need to capture a user id differently as in your example it's using a parameter and you have none in your route

Comment: it gives me cannot get ._id of null

Comment: Req.params.id is not there. So you need a correct value for it

Comment: You can now see it